# Which is greater among $I$ and $J$?

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality

If  $$I:=\int_{\frac{7}{3}}^\frac{49}{9}\frac{x^{6}}{1+x^{29}}dx$$ and if $$J:=\int_{\frac{7}{3}}^\frac{49}{9} \frac{x^{9}}{1+x^{17}}dx$$, then which is greater among $I$ and $J$ ? I can't understand how to guess this without integrating both $I$ and $J$. Because as far as I can guess integrating both $I$ and $J$ separately and then comparing between them will be very much difficult and length also. If we carefully see then the limits are also very strange. Also I don't think that by rationalizing the denominator in both the cases will yeild any good result. So, please help me out with this question.

Comment: well, if $f \leq g$ then $\int f \leq \int g$. Did you try checking whether there is an inequality between the two integrands on the interval of integration?

Comment: The integrands don't coincide for $x>1$...the second is larger.

Answer (score 4):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:  For $x>1$ we have $$\frac {x^9}{1+x^{17}}>\frac {x^6}{1+x^{29}}$$ since $$x^9+x^{38}>x^6+x^{23}$$

(term by term).

Thus $J>I$.

Comment: Thank you very much@lulu and @Matthew Towers.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need of cross multiplication. We have $x^6<x^9$ and $1+x^{29}>1+x^{17},$ Thus
$${x^6\over 1+x^{29}}<{x^9\over 1+x^{17}}$$

If we consider another example $${x^6\over 1+x^{13}}< {x^9\over 1+x^{17}}$$ then the cross multiplication is useful.